# Comparing p-values from pairwise permutation tests

Tags: p-value, permutation-test

1. I have three time series A, B, and C with the same length.
2. Calculate pairwise measurements among A, B, and C, and perform pairwise permutation tests among A, B, and C for the correlation with the same number of surrogates N for each test. That gives p-value for the measurement for each pair.
3. Declare that I have more confidence in the measurement between A and B than in the measurement between B and C if the p-value for A and B is smaller than the p-value for B and C.

Is the last step ok?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is "No".

Basically you need to remember that p-values are random variables themselves and more importantly remember that the ["difference between significant and non-significant is often not significant"](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1198/000313006X152649).  Basically it is not hard to find a case where effect A is not significantly different from 0, but effect B is significantly different from 0 (at some specified significance level), but A and B are not significantly different from each other.  The same will be true of correlations like you are asking about.

A better approach may be to jointly model all 3 variables together, probably using a Bayesian model, then look at how the joint distribution of the correlations of interest looks.

Comment: Thanks for the answer though. I have waited for a long time and no one even made a single comment.

Comment: @rxu waiting for a few *hours* is not really "a long time" on CV, where (good) answers or comments may pop up only after days, weeks, months, or even years.

Comment: I got it. you are right in the sense that if measurement X is significant and measurement Y is insignificant, it does not mean that measurement X - Y is significant. Here I am directly comparing the degree of significance for measurement between A and B with the degree of significance of measurement between B and C. The sampling size for both measurements are the same and I am not doing a subtraction here, so it will be fine, I guess.

Comment: Thanks for writing this. I realized if I use p-values as my new measurement, it purely just reflect the confidence in rejecting the null hypothesis.